# Retrieve detailed gene descriptions

Tags: r, gene, sequence-annotation, public-databases

Given a list of gene IDs, how do you retrieve the gene description, summary and other detailed information in R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### MyGene.info

Using the [R package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/mygene.html) for the [MyGene.info database](http://mygene.info):

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("mygene")

library(mygene)
gene <- getGene("1017", fields="all")
gene$summary
```

Multiple genes:

```
gene <- getGenes(c(1347:1350), fields="summary")
```

---

### Entrez database

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ropensci/rentrez")

library(rentrez)
genes <- entrez_summary(db="gene", id=c(718,720))
genes$`720`$summary
```

Comment: Nice question (and answer, I didn't know about MyGene), if you know what you are looking for maybe it is worth to mention biomaRt

Answer (score 8):

Description of how to use biomaRt [here](http://www.ensembl.org/info/data/biomart/biomart_r_package.html). Filter by your list of gene IDs. Get the descriptions etc as attributes. Eg:

```
> library(biomaRt)
> ensembl = useEnsembl(biomart="ensembl", dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
> IDs <- c("BRCA2","BRAF")
genedesc <- getBM(attributes=c('external_gene_name','description'), filters = 'external_gene_name', values = IDs, mart =ensembl)
> genedesc
  external_gene_name                                                                      description
1               BRAF B-Raf proto-oncogene, serine/threonine kinase [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1097]
2              BRCA2                  BRCA2, DNA repair associated [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1101]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not find a way to return detailed information  using biomaRt. The description fields are just extended gene names.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and fastest method (which also doesn’t require internet access) is to use [annotation packages](http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.9/bioc/vignettes/AnnotationDbi/inst/doc/IntroToAnnotationPackages.pdf), e.g. [org.Mm.eg.db](http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.9/data/annotation/html/org.Mm.eg.db.html):

```
library(AnnotationDbi)
library(org.Mm.eg.db)


# 1:1 mapping symbol→entrez
entrez_ids <- mapIds(org.Mm.eg.db, gene_symbols, 'ENTREZ', 'SYMBOL')

# 1:n mapping symbol→…
print(columns(org.Mm.eg.db))  # check what you can query
df <- select(org.Mm.eg.db, gene_symbols, c(...), 'SYMBOL')
```